# Determine the tangent space of the boundary of a manifold of the form $f(\mathbb R^d)$ for a differentiable $f$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, frechet-derivative, tangent-spaces

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$;
- $x^\ast\in\mathbb R^d$;
- $k\in\mathbb N$;
- $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^k$ be Fréchet differentiable at $x^\ast$;
- $v^\ast:=f(x^\ast)$;
- $A:={\rm D}f(x)$;
- $M:=f(\mathbb R^d)$.

Assume there is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from an open neighorhood $\Omega$ of $v^\ast$ in $M$ onto an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb H^k:=\mathbb R^{k-1}\times\{0\}$; i.e. $\Omega$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^k$.

We can easily show that$^1$ $\mathcal R(A)\subseteq T_{v^\ast}\:M$. If $A$ is surjective, then this is even an equality.

> Now assume $\operatorname{rank}A=k-1$. How can we show that $\mathcal R(A)=T_{v^\ast}\:\partial M$?

My idea is as follows: Assume the claim is wrong. Since $\dim\mathcal R(A)=k-1=\dim T_{v^\ast}\:\partial M$, it must hold $\mathcal R(A)\not\subseteq T_{v^\ast}\:\partial M$. So, there is a $v\in\mathcal R(A)\setminus T_{v^\ast}\:\partial M$. Since $v\in\mathcal R(A)$, there is a $h\in\mathbb R^d$ with $v=Ah$ and we easily see that $$\gamma(t):=f(x^\ast+th)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\mathbb R$$ is a $C^1$-curve on $M$ through $x^\ast$ with $\gamma'(0)$. Thus, $$v\in T_{v^\ast}M\tag1.$$ By $(1)$ and $v\not\in T_{v^\ast}\:\partial M$, we can conclude that $v$ is either inward or outward pointing.

> This *should* be a contradiction to the definition of $M$, since for small enough $t$, either $\gamma(t)$ or $-\gamma(t)$ should move outside the set $M=f(\mathbb R^d)$; which is clearly impossible by definition of $\gamma$.
>
> But how can we argue rigorously?

---

$^1$ The tangent space $T_{v^\ast}\:M$ is the set of all $\gamma'(0)$, where $\gamma$ is a $C^1$-curve on $M$ though $v^\ast$.

Comment: How could $y$ be from the boundary if $\Omega$ is open.

Comment: And you already defined $y=f(x)$, presumably with some $x\in\Omega$.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli I'm sorry, I've mistakenly denoted the domain of $f$ and the chart $\phi$ by the same symbol $\Omega$. Fixed now.

Comment: @TedShifrin Please take note of my edit; I've mistakenly used the symbol $\Omega$ for two different things.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've edited the question once again; I think it is way clearer now for what I'm asking. Please take a look at it.